# Does space behave like a logical operator that applies rules to its elements?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-physics, physics

I am asking due to being inspired by the following:

Consider a particle system with uniform motion in vacuum not sensitive towards fluctuations, such that classical mechanics applies.

Now, consider the motion time point per time point:

Due to being uniformly moving, for any t_1, the new location is a function of a direct prior state at t_0 by addition of some fixed vector.

Now, since at any t_i the system is resting, and from a given fixed set of statememts you can't derive anything new without invoking an exteriorly applied rule of inferrence, something must apply an operation to induce the change for the uniform motion that is not within the system itself (else it should transform and be identical simultaneously).

How exactly may that happen within space? What conveys the continuous application of this uniform motion jump sequence?

Is it space itself that provides the operation?

Comment: Is the system is in uniform motion, how is it at rest at any time t_i?

Comment: You seem to be conflating "space is like a logical operator" with "a certain idealization of space can be modeled with an operator that is like a logical operator". These are two quite different claims.

Comment: You have to be aware that no "space" ever exists. Space is formed of interacting elements. For simplicity, we class them as "space".

Comment: Your puzzle lies in holding the view of Newtonian absolute metric space, under relationalism universal (covering) space is an illusion *arising* from certain relation of different conceptual base entities, and of course this doesn't prevent other cause sufficiently induces your concerned operations such as the single most important schemata in this world time as the sensuous condition under which alone the pure conceptual rule of inference can be applied...

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit out on a limb answering this. You may get better answers on Physics SE or find someone to tell you all about exactly how I've made mistakes on Mathematics SE. Damn the torpedoes, full speed ahead.

---

A mathematical space is a structured set.

The kind of space you're used to calling space has a one-to-one mapping to a three dimensional mathematical metric space, which is a set of points structured by rules for determining *distance* and *direction*.

Objects in a region of physical space (particles, physicists, bananas) are not elements of the corresponding mathematical space (points), but the rules of the mathematical space do help describe some of their characteristics: the distances and directions between the points where the objects or their constituent parts are located, and hence also their volumes, shapes, orientations, etc.

We have historically found it more useful/more possible to describe objects using other mathematical objects (or less-well-defined but more intuitive approximate abstract objects) which are associated with points in space than to try to pack everything we know about how to predict the behavior of reality into one mathematical object.

If we did do so, such a mathematical object would have to be a mathematical space: a structured set whose elements were the constituent parts of all physical things, and whose structure was all physical law. However, it would be a big stretch to ask anybody except for a mathematician to call it *space*. It wouldn't be a coordinate system, or anything with a 1:1 mapping to a coordinate system. It would be all the laws of physics rolled up into one mathematical object. Most physicists would call it a *theory of quantum gravity*. Astronomers would call it a *theory of cosmology*. Regular people would just call it *the laws of physics* or *the universe*.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be making the assumption that at some time t the state of the system can be defined in terms of a fixed set of statements such as

'Particle 1 is now at x1,y1,z1',

'Particle 2 is now at x2,y2,z2',

etc etc etc

And then you are saying that there needs to be some kind of logical operation to account for the fact that the set of statements changes when the particles move to new positions at a later t. No, not really. Instead just consider your fixed set of statements to be:

'Particle 1 is at x1,y1,z1, moving with velocity v'

'Particle 2 is at x2,y2,z2, moving with velocity v'

etc etc

Incidentally, if all the particles are moving with the same velocity, you can adopt a reference frame in which the velocity is zero, and then there is no 'uniform motion jump sequence' to worry about.